# Is there a native/reliable alternative for boost::shared_ptr in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, tr1

My company doesn't allow the use of `boost` (for many stupid reasons, but that's off-topic).

I feel very frustrated having to use raw pointers when I'm used to `shared_ptr`, `weak_ptr` and `scoped_ptr` for personal development.

We're working exclusively with Microsoft compilers (Visual Studio 2010) and I wonder if there was an alternative to those templates that would decrease my pain.

I once heard of `std::tr1` but I'm not sure what this is. I believe it is some kind of Microsoft implementation of the next standard but can we rely on it ? What does it provide ? Is there any guarantees ? What headers should be included ?

Comment: Um, while boost, and the stl, are very very good wheels which (im told) one should endeavor to avoid re-inventing - and there is a lot to be said in favor of using a standardized smart pointer - they are really not hard to make.

Comment: @Chris Becke: If there is no other solution, I will have to do mine in the end yes. But if there is any way to use something made by people way smarter than me, I want to know how ;)

Comment: Please don't tease us with the '(for many stupid reasons, but that's off-topic)'!:-) I, for one, would love to know the stupid reasons!

Comment: @Sam: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529841/am-i-an-idealist

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With VC10 just use the [`shared_ptr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982026.aspx), [`weak_ptr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982126.aspx) and [`unique_ptr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410601.aspx) implementations it already provides. All you have to do is to include `<memory>`.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work (despite the fact that I had to specify `std::tr1` while the documentation states that `shared_ptr` is in `std`). What will happen when the next `C++` will be implemented by Microsoft. Will they suddenly drop support for `tr1` ? Should I use an alias for the namespace ?

Comment: @ereOn: That is strange, i don't have any problem using `std::shared_ptr` in VC10 - there should be no need for work-arounds.

Comment: I'm compiling using command-line, with "locally-optimized" makefiles... I wouldn't be surprised if one somehow disabled some features in the common makefiles. Or perhaps it is still using VC8 compiler. Is there a way to bring `std::tr1` into `std` ? (Is it even a good idea ?)

Comment: Don't mess around with `std::tr1`. It will continue to serve as a warning to future readers that you're still using a pre-standard version of `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @ereOn: I'd investigate the VC version first via e.g. `_MSC_VER`. In the absence of template aliases there is no completely satisfying solution as far as i know.

Comment: @MSalters: Thanks, it make sense. @Georg Fritzsche: Thanks again for everything.

Answer (score 4):

[TR1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1) is short for Technical Report 1 and are recommendations to the standard committee for new features in the C++ standard. take a look at the header  (or other headers that it includes). and if VS2010 implements TR1 there is a good chance you will have the tr1 smart pointers. These should be identical to the Boost smart pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the highlights. Indeed, it seems that it provides `shared_ptr`.